# Firebase function won't launch

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

Hi I'm developping a little API with firebase's functions. Everything worked great until today for no reason. When I'm trying to launch the server I get this error

```
Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

It says to go see firebase-debug.log. At the end of the file I have this:

```
[debug] [2021-11-18T13:27:28.923Z] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rows')
    at new Table (C:\Users\Isai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cli-table\lib\index.js:51:15)
    at Command.actionFn (C:\Users\Isai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\commands\emulators-start.js:47:33)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

After trying to uninstall it and install it again the error is still the same.
Does someone know what it's causing the error please ?

Comment: i am also experiencing this

Answer (score 1):

I fix this big checking if options was defined in the index.js at line 51 but I don't know what cause it at the first place